# Apache Lucene performance estimation

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I have a single TSV file with 2 columns, ID and Body. This is quite large, around 50GB.
This file is static and no modification. I will create the index once.

I want to index it using Lucene and make an exact ID search engine.
The use case is very simple, I want to search the ID and get the Body.
This will be a local application so the index would be in local directory and the app will be run locally.

The performance that I aim to get is around 15K query per seconds.
I have tried with 2 simple entries in the index and it takes 15ms to query 1 entry. This is very slow.
Do you think this use case and performance target is possible using Apache Lucene?